# GP + Tensorflow training

Tags: gpflow

I am trying to train a GPR model and a tensorflow model together. The training part has no issue. But for prediction using the trained model I receive a type error in a tf.placeholder op.

```python
pred, uncp=sess.run([my, yv], feed_dict={X:xtr})
```

The code is similar to the 2nd example from https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced_usage.html

```python
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import gpflow
float_type = gpflow.settings.float_type
gpflow.reset_default_graph_and_session()

def cnn_fn(x, output_dim):    
    out= tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=output_dim, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print(out)    
    return out

N = 150
xtr = np.random.rand(N,1)
ytr = np.sin(12*xtr) + 0.66*np.cos(25*xtr) + np.random.randn(N,1)*0.1 + 3
xtr = np.random.rand(N,28)
print(xtr.shape, ytr.shape)
nepoch=50
gp_dim=xtr.shape[1]
print(gp_dim)
minibatch_size = 16

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, gp_dim]) 
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

with tf.variable_scope('cnn'):
    f_X = tf.cast(cnn_fn(X, gp_dim), dtype=float_type)

k = gpflow.kernels.Matern52(gp_dim)
gp_model = gpflow.models.GPR(f_X, tf.cast(Y, dtype=float_type), k)

loss = -gp_model.likelihood_tensor
m, v = gp_model._build_predict(f_X)
my, yv = gp_model.likelihood.predict_mean_and_var(m, v)

with tf.variable_scope('adam'):
    opt_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

tf_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='adam')
tf_vars += tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='cnn')

## initialize
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=tf_vars))
gp_model.initialize(session=sess)

for i in range(nepoch):
    shind=np.array(range(len(xtr)))
    np.random.shuffle(shind)
    for j in range(int(len(xtr)/minibatch_size)):
        ind=shind[j*minibatch_size: (j+1)*minibatch_size]
        sess.run(opt_step, feed_dict={X:xtr[ind], Y:ytr[ind]})
```

Executing the code above runs fine. But adding the following line gives an error:

```
 pred, uncp=sess.run([my, yv], feed_dict={X:xtr})
```

with the following error:

```
<ipython-input-25-269715087df2> in <module>
----> 1 pred, uncp=sess.run([my, yv], feed_dict={X:xtr})

[...]

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
     [[node Placeholder_1 (defined at <ipython-input-24-39ccf45cd248>:2)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code fails is because you are not actually feeding in a value to one of the placeholders. This is easier to spot if you actually give them names:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, gp_dim], name='X') 
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='Y')
```

Tensorflow requires the entire compute graph to be well-defined, *and the `GPR` model you are using depends on both `X` **and** `Y`*. If you run the following line, it works fine:

```
pred, uncp = sess.run([my, yv], feed_dict={X: xtr, Y: ytr})
```

**Update**: as *user1018464* pointed out in the comment, you are using the `GPR` model, in which the predictions directly depend on the training data (e.g. see equations (2.22) and (2.23) on page 16 of http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf). Hence you will need to pass in both `xtr` and `ytr` to make predictions.

Other models such as `SVGP` represent the function through "inducing features", commonly "pseudo input/output" pairs that summarise the data, in which case you won't need to feed in the original input values at all (I got it wrong when I first answered).

You could set up the model as follows:

```
gp_model = gpflow.models.SVGP(f_X, tf.cast(Y, dtype=float_type), k, gpflow.likelihoods.Gaussian(), xtr.copy(), num_data=N)
```

Then `pred, uncp=sess.run([my, yv], feed_dict={X:xtr})` works as expected.

If you want to predict at different points `Xtest`, you need to set up a separate placeholder, and reuse the cnn (note the `reuse=True` in the variable_scope with the same name), as in example 2 of the notebook:

```
Xtest = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, Mnist.input_dim], name='Xtest')

with tf.variable_scope('cnn', reuse=True):
    f_Xtest = tf.cast(cnn_fn(Xtest, gp_dim), dtype=float_type)
```

Set up the model as before using `f_X`, but use `f_Xtest` in the call to `_build_predict`:

```
m, v = gp_model._build_predict(f_Xtest)
my, yv = gp_model.likelihood.predict_mean_and_var(m, v)
```

Now you need to pass in both `X`, `Y`, *and* `Xtest` into the session's run():

```
pred, uncp = sess.run([my, yv], feed_dict={X: xtr, Y: Ytr, Xtest: xtest})
```

where `xtest` is the numpy array with points at which you want to predict.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I add pred, uncp = sess.run([my, yv], feed_dict={X: xtr, Y: np.zeros_like(ytr)}) The prediction will be all zeros. if I change the code pred, uncp = sess.run([my, yv], feed_dict={X: xtr, Y: ytr}) , the predictions are correct.  I have two questions here: 1) why for prediction we need to feed the ytr data given that the model is already trained, 2) And how I can use the trained model for prediction, in this case I don't know what are y values. Thx

Comment: A Gaussian process is a non-parametric model, which means that it effectively has an infinite number of parameters. We cannot represent an infinite number of parameters, but we can compute the predictions directly from the dataset. This is why we need to keep the data around.

The model SVGP works more like a neural network, in which we learn an approximation to the true predictions which are summarised in a finite number of values. After these values are learned, the dataset can be forgotten when making predictions.

Comment: Thx for replying, if you go to gpflow page it provides an example for GPR not in a tensorflow framework, https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/regression.html ,,,, in the example there is no need for y data for inference , I have already implemented spvg but I am interested in GPR model not approximations. When gp model is trained it should be able to do inference without yvalues.

Comment: For a GPR model without any sparse approximations as you want it, the predictions **do** directly depend on the training values, so whatever you do you'll need to store them in some form -- the `GPR` model in GPflow does this implicitly, in the model.X and model.Y `DataHolder` instances (try changing their value - the predictions will change!)... The "training" in GPR is a training of the *hyperparameter* values (kernel lengthscales and variance, likelihood (noise) variance)...

Answer (score 0):

The GPflow manages TensorFlow sessions for you and you don't need to create your own TF session, when you use GPflow alone. In your case, `tf.layers.dense` makes 
 new variables, which should be initialized and I would advise to use a session which were created by GPflow. Essentially, you need to replace these lines

```
## initialize
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=tf_vars))
gp_model.initialize(session=sess)
```

with:

```
sess = gpflow.get_default_session()
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=tf_vars)
```

or wrap your code with default session context:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    ... build and run
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have implemented the changes suggested but the problem exists. Still I need to feed values of y for inference which I believe if that is the case is a bug in gpflow. After building/training the model the prediction should be done without using any y values. Otherwise what is the point of having a model.

Comment: @SimaDidari, check http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf (2.21) and (2.22), your predictive distribution depends on training data - X and Y.

Comment: That is correct, But how we do inference using the trained model, to calculate p(f∗|x∗, X, y) we need to have x & y (which are training points) but how are we feeding X* in the graph?  What are the values of X& Y in the feeddict here : pred, uncp=sess.run([my, yv], feed_dict={X:xest, y:?}), shouldnt we have three placeholder for X*, X & Y ?

Comment: This answer makes a good point about session handling but doesn't actually answer the original question... Sima Didari, you are right, if you want to predict at different points Xtest you also need to feed those into the graph! I've updated the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56083902/10445466 accordingly.